# Atomic number of $\rm CO_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, molecules

I have to calculate the Bethe-Bloch equation for a $\rm CO_2$ absorber, I know this is a stupid question, but is Atomic number additive? Or do I need to do something a little more complex?

I was think Z = 22 since C has 6 protons and O has 8, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant term is the electron number density.  So you can safely treat $\rm CO_2$ as "a thing" with $Z=22, A=44,$, mass 44 grams/mole (with more significant digits from a reference, if you like).

Comment: So what confused me is that there is a thing called effective atomic number.